How to remove json elements and reformat it
I have the follow JSON as an output of an enumerate function.
{'question': (0, 'Who invented the light bulb?'), 'answers': [{'answer': 'Thomas Edison', 'score': '2.0'}, {'answer': 'Nikola Tesla', 'score': '2.0'}, {'answer': 'Albert Einstein', 'score': '0.0'}], 'error': "We didn't quite get that"}

How can I remove the 0 and the enclosing bracket so it looks like this.
{'question': 'Who invented the light bulb?', 'answers': [{'answer': 'Thomas Edison', 'score': '2.0'}, {'answer': 'Nikola Tesla', 'score': '2.0'}, {'answer': 'Albert Einstein', 'score': '0.0'}], 'error': "We didn't quite get that"}

I'd appreciate any python or Regex solution. Thank you.

What is the pattern/logic?

How would you expect to be able to use re to change a tuple? Also, that's not valid JSON. You can have tuples as dictionary values in Python but not in JSON

I just found out that I could simply use an underscore (_) for my enumerate counter to show that I won't use the variable.
Like so:
for _, value in enumerate(my_list):

I had initially used:
for i, value in enumerate(my_list) 

but a Ruff linter in the repository I needed to push the code to kept raising issues with i not being used.

Well done. You should probably edit the question, because this explains how you don't have to ask the (current) question, but isn't technically a correct answer how to get from (current) A to B that others could use.

output = {
    "question": (0, "Who invented the light bulb?"),
    "answers": [
        {"answer": "Thomas Edison", "score": "2.0"},
        {"answer": "Nikola Tesla", "score": "2.0"},
        {"answer": "Albert Einstein", "score": "0.0"},
    ],
    "error": "We didn't quite get that",
}
question = list(output["question"])
output["question"] = question[1]

print(output)


You don't show your use of enumerate so I'll answer the question as written.
d = {
    "question": (0, "Who invented the light bulb?"),
    "answers": [
        {"answer": "Thomas Edison", "score": "2.0"},
        {"answer": "Nikola Tesla", "score": "2.0"},
        {"answer": "Albert Einstein", "score": "0.0"},
    ],
    "error": "We didn't quite get that",
}

d["question"] = d["question"][1]

